# Information about Indian court cases available online

Tags: india

Based on my experience searching for information about Indian court cases online, the only information that is available online for a case is the Court Judgment. This is the document authored by a judge (or judges) giving their decision on a case.

However, this information is by definition incomplete. I would like as complete a description of the case as possible, in particular including the submissions from the plaintiff/petitioner, as well as responses etc. The judgment by itself just includes whatever the judges feel like mentioning from the case documentation, and it's wholly inadequate as documentation of a case. If the other information is not recorded in an accessible form, that would be most unfortunate.

So, I was wondering whether this information was available online, possibly as a paid service. If not, why not? While this seems like a obvious and simple question, I've not found any clear statement of this anywhere. However, given that I have failed to find it so far, it at least seems that this information, even if available somewhere, is not very accessible.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for trial court records rather than appellate court decisions (which are easier to obtain) is this correct?

Comment: Hi ohwilleke. I'm not sure. One reason for asking this question was because researching case law is obviously easier with complete information. Another part was because I was planning to try to find a suitable lawyer by researching cases and working backwards from there. And obviously complete court records would help for that. Why do you say that appellate court decisions would be easier to obtain? (See also my comments on DaleM's answer below.)

Comment: There are regularly maintained record of important appellate court opinions which are called "case reporters" or reports for short, which keep track of those decisions in all common law countries because the rules of law articulated in those cases are precedents with the force of law in future cases. Lots of relevant law is only generated in that fashion. Trial court decisions and the trial court records in appellate court cases don't have legal effect as precedents so they aren't important for the general public to have access to. If the appellate court doesn't mention it, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi @ohwilleke, as I already mentioned, my use case is to try to learn more about specific lawyers and their cases. So for me, those records *are* important. I suppose by "they aren't important for the general public to have access to" means that not enough people with influence care about maintaining proper records for it to happen. Also, searching for "appellate courts" for India doesn't bring up much of anything. There don't seem to be courts with that actual designation here, though the High Courts and Supreme Courts seem to serve those functions

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if the distinction between trial and appellate courts exists over here. Doesn't trial court mean trial by jury? And as far as I can tell, jury trials don't exist in India. At least, I've never heard of one. This is supported by Wikipedia, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury_trial#India.

Comment: Actually, I think my last statement was wrong. I suppose judges can conduct a trial on their own, and in the absence of juries, I suppose that is how it works in India. But I'm still fuzzy about the distinction between trial and appellate courts, and why it would be more important to preserve records of one vs the other. So, an appellate court case is just an appeal of a case that has already been heard, right? So, why would this merit special attention, and how is it really different from a trial case, since it just amounts to a retrying of the case in front of a possibly different judge?

Comment: An "appellate court" is a court that is hearing a case in an appellate capacity reviewing on appeal a decision of a lower trial court, even if the same judges sometime hear cases in a trial court capacity. Appellate decisions make binding law that affect future cases involving unrelated parties. Trial court decisions don't. An appeal is not merely a retrial of a case, it is a review of whether the judge made legally correct decisions in the trial court based upon the proceedings in the trial court. See https://www.animallaw.info/article/introduction-indian-judicial-system

Answer (score 2):

### The judgement is the definitive record

The [*Destruction of Records Act*](https://legislative.gov.in/sites/default/files/A1917-05.pdf) 1917 allow the high court to set [rules](https://highcourtchd.gov.in/sub_pages/left_menu/Rules_orders/high_court_rules/Vol-V--PDF/chap5partCV5.pdf) on what records are to be kept and for how long. In summary, a very small number, including the judgement are kept indefinitely and the remainder are split into Part A (important stuff) and Part B (less important stuff) and kept for 30 and 6 years respectively.

There is no obligation for these to be publicly available so, generally, they aren’t. They are usually publicly *accessible* by going to the register of the relevant court and asking to see them which may involve payment of an administrative fee. Some records are, however, classified or confidential depending on the nature of the case (e.g. national security, cases involving children etc.)

Once a case is completed and all avenues of review have been exhausted, the submissions and evidence are of no value. Only the fact of the case and the reasons in the judgement matter.

Comment: Hi Dale M, Some comments and questions. First, I don't agree with the statement that "The judgement is the definitive record". Where is this text from?  Is it a quote from somewhere, or a legal dogma/truism? I can think of all kind of scenarios where other documentation, particularly submissions from both parties, would be relevant, and possibly important. The judge could leave out important information in the judgment, or misrepresent it. This is hardly unlikely and may even
be relatively common, at least in India.

Comment: In any case, thank you very much for the pointer to "The Destruction of Records Act". I had no idea such a document existed. Since it sounds like you are not
yourself Indian (your name and location), were you already familiar with similar documents in other legal systems? And are such practices an international standard?

Comment: Also, where did you get the information about Part A and Part B being kept for 30 and 6 years respectively? I don't see this in "The Destruction of Records Act 1917". Can you reference this quote? And does the source specify what A and B would consist of? On doing a
search, it appears that some individual states have their own individual laws/acts on this topic. Though "The Destruction of Records Act 1917" is very old, being a British/colonial era law, it does not appear to have been superseded at the Central level.

Comment: Also, you write "the submissions and evidence are of no value". But this is only true in the sense that it may be of no use to the people involved in the case. It might be useful to other parties interested in case law. This is rather similar to the way that a question/answer thread on SE may be useful to others besides the original poster.

Comment: Finally, it seems to me that such considerations are somewhat obsolete, since in the age of computers, complete records can easily be scanned and kept indefinitely on a hard disk. Though of course, this would require the records to either be in electronic form in the
first place, or to be scanned. Unfortunately, India in the 21st century still relies heavily on perishable and hard to copy (or back up) paper documents.

Comment: @FaheemMitha People interested in case law can't use trial court records to support arguments in their own cases anyway (unless it involves parties related to the original ones).

Comment: @FaheemMitha it is true that it easier to store records - more people see that as a problem than those that see it as an advantage